# How can i print the report in excel format using aeroo report on Openerp7

Tags: excel, openerp-7, aeroolib

I want to print report in XLS format, using aeroo report on openerp 7, i have configure the input and the output in aeroo report interface. (see fig)

[image]

The problem is : how can i enter the data into ods file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dur searching and trying, I found the solution, for passing the data in xls file: 
Choose the cellule and insert a hyperlink, and write in window showing in target field : `python://o.your_field_name`

(for example display the object name):

[image]